# AJAX error handling for submit function in functions file

Tags: functions, ajax, curl

I have created a custom function in my `functions.php` to handle form submissions for a Mailchimp subscriber list. I am making an AJAX call in my JavaScript to process the PHP. The problem I am facing is that my AJAX call always returns "success" even when the Mailchimp function is not successful. When the Mailchimp subscribe function is successful it will return code `200`, when its unsuccessful it will return code `400`. How can I reconfigure my JS so that code `400` will fire the error function in the AJAX call?

Here's part of my PHP function:

```
curl_setopt($mchAPI, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . substr($apiKey, strpos($apiKey, '-') + 1) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . md5(strtolower($email)));
curl_setopt($mchAPI, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode('user:' . $apiKey)));
curl_setopt($mchAPI, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
curl_setopt($mchAPI, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($mchAPI, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($mchAPI, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($mchAPI, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($mchAPI, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($mchAPI, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$result = curl_exec($mchAPI);
$responseCode = curl_getinfo($mchAPI, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // This will return '200' if successful or '400' if unsuccessful
```

Here's my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: postURL, 
    method: 'POST',
    data: serialized,
    success: function(response) {
        // Always ends here even if subscribe is unsuccesful
        alert('SUCCESS!');
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownerror) {
        alert('FAILED ' + thrownerror);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I reconfigure my JS so that code `400` will fire the error
>   function in the AJAX call?

The `error` callback in your `$.ajax()` setup will be fired if the server responded with a HTTP status header *other than "OK" (code: `200`)*, so via the PHP function which handles the AJAX request, just send a HTTP status header with the code `400` ("Bad Request") when the `$responseCode` is `400`.

And you can send it using [`wp_die()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/):

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your-action', function(){
    ...
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($mchAPI, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // Send a response and the HTTP status header.
    if ( '200' == $responseCode ) {
        echo 'Subscribed'; // success message/data

        wp_die(); // here the code defaults to 200
    } else {
        echo 'Not subscribed'; // error message/data

        wp_die( '', 400 );
    }
} );
```

Or use [`status_header()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/status_header/) to send custom HTTP error message; i.e. other than the default `Bad Request` when the code is `400`:

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your-action', function(){
    ...
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($mchAPI, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // Send a response and the HTTP status header.
    if ( '200' == $responseCode ) {
        echo 'Subscribed'; // success message/data

        status_header( 200, 'OK' );
    } else {
        echo 'Not subscribed'; // error message/data

        status_header( 400, 'Custom HTTP Error' );
    }

    die(); // not wp_die()
} );
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you!